# More than 1 controller function name in URI

Tags: codeigniter

Using Codeigniter, I have a controller function name `search` that takes in parameters `state` and `city` in the URI segments `http://www.mysite.com/functionA/MA/Boston/0` where `0` is used by the pagination class.  The controller function declaration will thus look like:

```
function search(state, city) {
    ...
}
```

**Problem:** For SEO purposes and to get pretty URLs, I want `http://www.mysite.com/search/MA/Boston/view/12345` to show a particular page for product id `12345`. In this case, `View` is our second controller function defined by

```
function view(pid) {
    ...
}
```

And the first controller function `search` does not do anything in this case, its there in the URL just to make the URL pretty etc. So `view` is the only working controller function.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## URI Routing

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html

Something like this mayhaps?

```
//goes in application/config/routes.php
$route['search/(:any)/(:any)/view/(:num)'] = "view/$3";
```

This gets any URI that looks like `search/something/whatever/view/325` and reroutes it to `view/325`